# Exporting EAR file in Eclipse taking long time

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, export

I'm working on a project on Eclipse, more specific RAD build. The EAR file exported is around 40 mb, last week it was taking 1 minute, today its taking more than 10 minutes.
I didnt change much code, nor changed any config related to the JVM.

I export directly from RAD, right click on the project and export EAR.

So whats going wrong?

Comment: any console output that might be helpful?

Comment: the console dont write much when exporting EAR. 
I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it, but i Disabled all Validations in RAD. The building is little faster now, does it have anything to do with export though?
For anyone familiar with RAD, when exporting EAR, it just got stuck on the Exporting dialog until it writes the whole file. In the past it was writing 1-2 mb per second, now it barely write 200KB/s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is fixed, im not sure which of these fixed it, but one of them did:

- The output folder was shared on the network, stopped the sharing
- Defragmented the disk
- Emptied the Recycle Bin (it had almost 5 GB)

I made them all together, so i not sure which solved the problem, but i suspect one of the first two.
It was a an OS problem, nothing to do with Eclipse.

Comment: In such cases, i recommend to stop sharing the folder when building/deploying and defragment.

Comment: That's the issue. Eclipse breaks when you try to export an EAR to a network drive.

Answer (score 3):

Thoughts:

Clearly *something* is different. What could it be?

1. Your app: Could you now have lots more little graphics files or some such?
2. Your app: could you be referencing some external resource eg. XSDs from somewhere remote, is it generating code at this point with some such reference?
3. Environment: Disk drive. Are you exporting to some nearly full disk? Or a network drive that's suddenly really slow, or somehow a revision control system is trying to adopt what you are exporting.
4. Environment: Memory. I've seen Eclipse get stupidly slow when paging is happening. Could you just have increased your memory usage a tad or now be running something new in the background?

As none of those apply (you really sure?) then I would do this:

- take the app to another workspace
- take the app to another machine
- Break the app down to pieces, binary chop until you find what the expensive bit

Comment: i tried your second group of suggestions, actually its faster on my mate computer. So now i think it has nothing to do with Eclipse, might be n antivirus or a harddisk problem, will dig further.